# why SSRS asking to Define query parameters when already defined?

Tags: visual-studio, parameters, ssrs-2008

I have the below query which is working well in SQL. But when I use this query in ssrs(Visual studio 2015) it is giving me error saying define query parameters. I have already defined values for parametes but still getting the error. I feel something from the SQL query which s not getting supported in SSRS. Can anyone help?

```
[![SET FMTONLY OFF

USE GODSDB

declare
@start date = getdate() - 100
,   @end date = getdate()
drop table #CallLog
declare @code varchar(max), @TableName varchar(max), @SeverName varchar(max)
--IF object_id('tempdb..#CallLog') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #CallLog
CREATE TABLE #CallLog (
\[JurisdictionShortIdentifier\] VARCHAR(100),
    \[ContractCallLogOID\] INT,
    \[ContractCallLogProcessQueueOID\] INT,
    \[ContractOID\] INT,
    \[CallDate\] DATETIME,
    \[CallHandledBy\] VARCHAR(60),
    \[CallLogOldGreenUnit\] INT,
    \[CallLogNewGreenUnit\] INT,
    \[Comment\] VARCHAR(7500)
)

set @TableName = '#CallLog'
set @SeverName = 'BA_GBASSTOCSISDB' -- sp_linkedservers
set @code = '
;with XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT ''http://tempuri.org/GEOUnit.xsd'')
select

    ccl.JurisdictionShortIdentifier,
    ccl.ContractCallLogOID,
    que.ContractCallLogProcessQueueOID,
    ccl.ContractOID,
    ccl.db_insertDate as CallDate,
    ccl.db_insertBy as CallHandledBy,
    convert(xml, que.XMLString).value(''(/GEOUnit/GreenPowerUnits/GreenPowerUnitsOld)\[1\]'',''int'') as CallLogOldGreenUnit,
    convert(xml, que.XMLString).value(''(/GEOUnit/GreenPowerUnits/GreenPowerUnitsNew)\[1\]'',''int'') as CallLogNewGreenUnit,
    cmt.Comment
from CSISDB.dbo.ContractCallLog as ccl (nolock)
left join CSISDB.dbo.ContractCallLogProcessQueue as que (nolock) on ccl.ContractCallLogOID = que.ContractCallLogOID
left join CSISDB.dbo.Comment as cmt (nolock) on ccl.ContractCallLogOID = cmt.FKObjectOID and cmt.FKTableObjectOID = 1008
where 1 = 1
and ccl.ContractCallLogStatusIdentifier in (''GMOD'', ''GUS'', ''GI'')
and ccl.ContractCallLogReasonIdentifier in (''Changed'', ''GEOR'', ''NULL'', ''GEO'', ''GEO0'', ''GEO1'', ''GEO3'', ''GEO2'', ''CDR'', ''GEO4'', ''GEO5'', ''JUST GREEN adder'', ''JustGreen'')
--and ccl.JurisdictionShortIdentifier = ''AG''
and ccl.SourceSystemIdentifier = ''GBASS''
and ccl.db_insertDate between @start and @end
--and ccl.ContractCallLogOID = 57131879 --&gt; TEST CASE
'
set @code = replace(@code, '@start', '''' + convert(varchar, convert(date, @start, 101)) + '''')
set @code = replace(@code, '@end', '''' + convert(varchar, convert(date, dateadd(day, 1, @end), 101)) + '''')
set @code = concat('insert into ', @TableName, ' select * from openquery (', @SeverName, ', ''' , replace(@code, '''', '''''') , ''')')

print @code
exec(@code)

-- select * from #CallLog where ContractCallLogOID = 57707501

-- some call log have multiple process queues, delete the process queues that don't is not modifying the geo units
delete a
from #CallLog           as a
inner join #CallLog     as b    on a.ContractCallLogOID = b.ContractCallLogOID
                                and a.ContractCallLogProcessQueueOID != b.ContractCallLogProcessQueueOID
                                and a.CallLogNewGreenUnit is null
                                and b.CallLogNewGreenUnit is not null
--select * from #CallLog

select
    ccl.JurisdictionShortIdentifier,
    ccl.ContractCallLogOID,
    ccl.ContractCallLogProcessQueueOID,
    cnt.RtlrContractIdentifier,
    ccl.ContractOID,
    cst.ContractStatusIdentifier as ContractStatus,
    ccl.CallLogOldGreenUnit,
    ccl.CallLogNewGreenUnit,
    cur.GreenLevelIndicator as CurrentGreenUnit,
    cur.db_insertDate as GreenUnitLastUpdateDate,
    cur.db_insertBy as GreenUnitLastUpdateBy,
    ccl.CallDate,
    ccl.CallHandledBy,
    ccl.Comment
from #CallLog                       as ccl
inner join Contract                 as cnt (nolock) on ccl.ContractOID = cnt.ContractOID
                                                    and ccl.CallLogOldGreenUnit != ccl.CallLogNewGreenUnit
inner join ContractState            as cst (nolock) on cnt.ContractOID = cst.ContractOID
left join ContractGreenContent      as cur (nolock) on cnt.ContractOID = cur.ContractOID
                                                    and isnull(cur.EffectiveEndDate, dateadd(day, 1, getdate())) >= getdate()
left join ContractGreenContent      as his (nolock) on cnt.ContractOID = his.ContractOID
                                                    and ccl.CallLogNewGreenUnit = his.GreenLevelIndicator
                                                    and his.db_insertDate between dateadd(day, -1, ccl.CallDate) and dateadd(day, 1, ccl.CallDate)
where his.ContractGreenContentOID is null
--select * from #CallLog
union all

select
ccl.JurisdictionShortIdentifier,
    ccl.ContractCallLogOID,
    ccl.ContractCallLogProcessQueueOID,
    cnt.RtlrContractIdentifier,
    ccl.ContractOID,
    cst.ContractStatusIdentifier as ContractStatus,
    ccl.CallLogOldGreenUnit,
    ccl.CallLogNewGreenUnit,
    cur.GreenLevelIndicator as CurrentGreenUnit,
    cur.db_insertDate as GreenUnitLastUpdateDate,
    cur.db_insertBy as GreenUnitLastUpdateBy,
    ccl.CallDate,
    ccl.CallHandledBy,
    ccl.Comment
from #CallLog                       as ccl
inner join Contract                 as cnt (nolock) on ccl.ContractOID = cnt.ContractOID
                                                    and isnull(ccl.CallLogOldGreenUnit, 0) = isnull(ccl.CallLogNewGreenUnit, 0)
inner join ContractState            as cst (nolock) on cnt.ContractOID = cst.ContractOID
left join ContractGreenContent      as cur (nolock) on cnt.ContractOID = cur.ContractOID
                                                    and isnull(cur.EffectiveEndDate, dateadd(day, 1, getdate())) >= getdate()

SET FMTONLY ON][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your parameter names and SQL variables are all spelled exactly the same, they are case sensitive.

Also try declaring each variable on it own line with its own DECLARE statement. I've seen this fix this issue 'sometimes'

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are inside your @SQL query variable. The server that you are running the OPENQUERY from doesn't recognize the parameters since they were declared on another server.

Put the parameter declarations inside your SQL variable:

```
set @code = '
declare
@start date = getdate() - 100
,   @end date = getdate()
...
```